# socket.io: How to get socket variable from other socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

There are two players in one room.

Every player has a color saved as a socket variable:

```
socket.on('join', function(color){socket.color = color});
```

It is easy to get this color variable, when the client with this color triggers the request:

```
socket.on('own_color', function(){

    console.log('own color:     ' + socket.color);

});
```

But now we need the color of the other player.
Maybe we can get it somehow by using the other player's socket id:

```
socket.on('partner color', function(){

    var partnerid = io.sockets.clients('room1')[0].id;
    var partnercolor = '????????'

    console.log('partner color     ' + partnercolor);

});
```

Do you know how to get the color of the other player?

Comment: we are searching for code that looks like : `partnercolor = io.sockets.manager.partnerid.color;`   (The code in this comment doesn't work of course. We just want to explain the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, you're calling `io.listen` - make sure you store that result:

```
socketio = io.listen(...)
```

Then, you can get the socket object based on a socket ID:

```
socketio.sockets.sockets[idSocket]
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to communicate over the socket, requesting the data you need. The socket connections itself are just a transport. If you need to know something "emit" a question
and on the other side listen ("on") for that question and respond accordingly

guessing io.sockets.clients('room1') is a list of all clients in that room
then:

```
io.sockets.clients('room1')[0].emit('request color');
io.sockets.clients('room1')[0].on('respond color', function (color) {
  console.log('color received', color);
});
```

and on the other side

```
socket.on('request color', function () {
  socket.emit(color);
});
```

Comment: we edited the question to make it more easy to understand. Our question is about how to access the socket variable of another client. Thank you for your answer anyways.

Comment: im asuming your 2 players (A and B) each use a browser and get their socket connections from the server, if A wants B's color it should have to ask for it, and in turn the server should ask B and respond with B's awnser to A; A and B do not have a direct connection, right?

Comment: setting some variable on a socket at client side doesnt notify the server of that information, and all communication needs to go trough the server, so youll have to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aaron Dufour we can now post the missing snippet:

```
socket.on('partner color', function(){

    var partnerid = io.sockets.clients('room1')[0].id;
    var partnercolor = io.sockets.sockets[partnerid].color;
    console.log('partner color:  '+ partnercolor);

});
```

Our server combines express and socket.io, so maybe someone is interested, how io.listen is called in this case:

```
var express = require('express')
    , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);
```